# How to move raphael set?

Tags: positioning, raphael

I have a set of objects grouped with `Raphael.set()`. What I want to do is to move the whole set (change `x` and `y` coordinates) from one place to another. 
How I can move the whole set as a single object? 
What I found already is that when an `.attr({X: newX, Y: newY})` is called every element from the set will be positioned on this coordinated which will result in piling all the elements in one place.

Answer (score 15):

Edit: Refer to [Rick Westera's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15539752/524555) as `translate` is now deprecated.

Use `.translate(x, y)`, example:

```
var paper = Raphael('stage', 300, 300);
var set = paper.set();
set.push(paper.rect(0,0,30,50));
set.push(paper.circle(40,50,10));
set.push(paper.path("M 0 70 L 100 70"));
set.translate(100, 100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q4vUx/

Comment: if you want it to be a bit more graphic, this may help http://jsfiddle.net/q4vUx/1/

Comment: translate is being deprecated, use transform (see my answer below)

Answer (score 9):

Use `transform('Tx,y')` as translate is deprecated. For example:

```
var paper = Raphael('stage', 300, 300);
var set = paper.set();
set.push(paper.rect(0, 0, 100, 100));
set.push(paper.text(50, 50, "Foo"));
set.transform("T100,50");
```

Note that there are two types of translation:

- 'T100,50' will move the set 100px to the right and 50 down using the global axis.
- 't100,50' will do the same but using the set's local axis (ie. it depends on which way the set has been rotated).

Answer (score 2):

This is what i'm using to reposition a set, in my case is a set of fonts returned by Paper.print() but i think it should work with any kind of set.

```
var glyphs = paper.print(0, 0, text, paper.getFont(font, 800), fontSize).hide();
glyphs.transform('...T' + [posx, posy] + 'R' + [angle, posx, posy]).show();
```

hope it helps.